# Angular-Chart not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm building an app using AngularJS. In this app I want to show a line-chart with some data. I got a page with two 'tabs'. I used my own implementation for this:
Two buttons at the top, `$scope.graph.visible` boolean which is being set by clicking those buttons.

This is the chart in the HTML:

```
<canvas 
  data="{{graph.data}}"
  labels="{{graph.labels}}"
  options="{{graph.options}}"
  legend="{{graph.legend}}"

  ng-show="{{graph.visible}}">
</canvas>
```

In the controller I got this:

```
  $scope.graph.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  $scope.graph.labels = ['hoi', 'doei', 'hallo', 'hee', 'hoi', 'doei', 'hallo', 'hee',];
  $scope.graph.options = {
    animation: false
  };
  $scope.graph.legend = true;
```

In the source of the page I see this (when the graph should be visible):

```
<canvas data="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" labels="["hoi","doei","hallo","hee","hoi","doei","hallo","hee"]" options="{"animation":false}" series="" colours="" getcolour="" click="" hover="" legend="true" ng-show="true" class="ng-hide" style="">
</canvas>
```

EDIT// I wonder why it has the class `ng-hide`

EDIT2// When I manually remove the `ng-hide` class I can see a white block with web inspector. Otherwise I can''t even find that.

EDIT3// Also, when I add `class=""` in the HTML-file, it doesn't remove the `ng-hide` class.

EDIT4// http://plnkr.co/edit/2Wr3HvMzcwfQG2tmsJgX?p=preview

Comment: any errors in console? can you provide jsfiddle ot plunker?

Comment: No errors in the console. Yes, I will provide a plunker or something in a few minutes!

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2Wr3HvMzcwfQG2tmsJgX?p=preview Here is a plunker! Hope you can help me!

Comment: you wrong use angular chart :-) just a minute, i provide a some fixing

Comment: Oh really? I am curious!

Comment: Please, ask only one question per topic.
If you've got another problem, create another topic. Espacialy if it's ionic related.

Comment: You're right. I asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819173/strange-angular-chartjs-issue-not-displaying-correctly-in-ionic-app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to use {{}} when it's data from the scope, so you have to change like this :

```
<canvas 
    class="chart chart-line"
    data="graph.data"
    labels="graph.labels"
    series="graph.series"
    options="graph.options"
    legend="graph.legend"
    ng-show="graph.visible">
  </canvas>
```

Furthermore, data should be an array of array like

```
$scope.graph.data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]];
```

See the working Plunker here (fixed by Grundy in the comments) : http://plnkr.co/edit/xQ42shTY6qrteNXOYX2F?p=preview

Comment: That's what I though too, but because without the curly braces it just prints "graph.visible" I put those around it. Now it prints "true" or "false". I know it's strange. I commented a plunker to the original post, check it out there!

Comment: When you don't you the bracket and you hover "canvas" in the dev tools you can see that it's there. Your problem is that "canvas" is not a directive or doesnt do anything.

Comment: When I remove it, the canvas is indeed visible (but still white ...), but it has `ng-show="graph.visible"` in the web-inspector. Is that good?

Comment: @XavierBalloy but _legend_ not change dynamic, i mean if on start `graph.legend` is _true_ legend always true, even if  set `graph.legend` to _false_

Comment: Thank you. The whole problem was that I didn't give it the `chart chart-line` class! When I did that, I indeed had to remove the curly braces. Now it is working! But now I wonder how I can hide the legend when the graph is hidden, since I don't make that element myself.

Comment: @JeroenJK just hide not graph element, but graph container like this http://plnkr.co/edit/xQ42shTY6qrteNXOYX2F?p=preview

Comment: @Grundy: I edited my answer to reference your Plunker :)

Comment: @XavierBalloy anyway i don't know why `legend="graph.legend"` not applied dynamically :-)

Answer (score 9):

Adding following `div` container over the `canvas` solved the problem for me, 
check the following:

```
<div class="chart-container" ng-show="graph.visible">
  <canvas #myChart class="my-4" width="900" height="380"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: @AnandA.S as I remember it was related to ng-show="graph.visible", but really not sure since this is an old answer though!